# Why vertical terminal resizing (shrinking) adds blank lines at the bottom?

Tags: c++, scroll, ncurses

I'm trying to learn ncurses writting code in C++. I use Linux Mint and g++ for compiling. I've written the below code. I have two subwindows created with newwin() that always keep their size. What i want is when i shrink the window and then expand nothing to change. When i shrink horizontally and then expand, the windows edges are drawn as expected, nothing is corrupted. But when i do the same thing vertically it looks like a **scrolling** is done and blank lines are added below. Why does this happen when the change is vertical but when it's horizontal everything is fine?

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <signal.h>


WINDOW * mainWin;
WINDOW * sideWin;
void resizeHandler(int);

int main()
{
    int mainwinStartX = 0;
    int mainwinStartY = 0;
    int mainwinWidth;
    int mainwinHeight;
    int sidewinStartX;
    int sidewinStartY = 0;
    int sidewinWidth;
    int sidewinHeight;
    signal(SIGWINCH, resizeHandler);

    initscr();
    noecho();
    refresh();

    // Prepairing mainWin sizes
    mainwinWidth = float(2)/3 * COLS;
    mainwinHeight = LINES;
    // Prepairing side win sizes
    sidewinStartX = mainwinWidth;
    sidewinWidth = COLS - mainwinWidth;
    sidewinHeight = LINES;
    // creating window objects
    mainWin = newwin(mainwinHeight, mainwinWidth, mainwinStartY, mainwinStartX);
    sideWin = newwin(sidewinHeight, sidewinWidth, sidewinStartY, sidewinStartX);
    box(mainWin, 0, 0);
    box(sideWin, 0, 0);
    wrefresh(mainWin);
    wrefresh(sideWin);
    while (getch() != 'x'){}
    endwin();
    return 0;
}


void resizeHandler(int sigNumber){}
```

Answer (score 1):

ncurses does/doesn't update layout of windows other than **`stdscr`** intentionally.  The behavior is described in the manual page for [`wresize`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/wresize.3x.html):

> This is an extension to the curses library.  It reallocates storage for
>   an ncurses window to adjust its dimensions to the specified values.  *If
>   either  dimension  is larger than the current values, the window's data
>   is filled with blanks that have the current  background  rendition  (as
>   set by **`wbkgdset`**) merged into them*.

ncurses does not attempt to guess the application's preferred layout.  The [`resizeterm`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/resizeterm.3x.html) manual page points out that an application should check for **`KEY_RESIZE`** returned from `wgetch` and update the layout:

> The  **`KEY_RESIZE`**  alerts  an  application  that  the screen size has changed, and that it should repaint special features such  as  pads
>   that cannot be done automatically.

The given example program has a couple of problems:

- it refers to a resize-handler (not shown) which is not needed (since `initscr` assigns one — see *[Signal Handlers](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-Signal-Handlers)* in the **initscr** manual page)
- the fragment shown here:

```
    box(mainWin, 0, 0);
    box(sideWin, 0, 0);
    wrefresh(mainWin);
    wrefresh(sideWin);
    while (getch() != 'x'){}
```

will not repaint the boxes in `mainWin` and `sideWin` because:

- with ncurses' signal handler, the loop with `getch` would repaint `stdscr`, wiping out the other windows.
- with some other signal handler, ncurses would not know that the screensize had changed, and you would get unpredictable results.

You *may* be seeing some partial overwrite of those windows; I only see the entire window being overwritten with the (blank) `stdscr`.

Comment: Thank's Thomas Dickey for the response!
Although i read it 4-5 times i didn't understand many things. Using the KEY_RESIZE definition though, as you suggested, helped a lot. Thank's again.

Answer (score 0):

The code that actually worked for me:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

#define WIDTH 80
#define HEIGHT 24

WINDOW * mainWin;
WINDOW * sideWin;

int main()
{
    int mainwinStartX = 0;
    int mainwinStartY = 0;
    int mainwinWidth;
    int mainwinHeight;
    int sidewinStartX;
    int sidewinStartY = 0;
    int sidewinWidth;
    int sidewinHeight;

    initscr();
    noecho();
    refresh();
    // Prepairing mainWin sizes
    mainwinWidth = float(2)/3 * WIDTH;
    mainwinHeight = HEIGHT;
    // Prepairing side win sizes
    sidewinStartX = mainwinWidth;
    sidewinWidth = WIDTH - mainwinWidth;
    sidewinHeight = HEIGHT;
    // creating window objects
    mainWin = newwin(mainwinHeight, mainwinWidth, mainwinStartY, mainwinStartX);
    sideWin = newwin(sidewinHeight, sidewinWidth, sidewinStartY, sidewinStartX);
    box(mainWin, 0, 0);
    box(sideWin, 0, 0);
    wrefresh(mainWin);
    wrefresh(sideWin);
    while (TRUE)
    {
        int input = getch();
        if (input == 'x')
            break;
        if (input == KEY_RESIZE)
        {
                refresh();
                delwin(mainWin);
                delwin(sideWin);
                mainWin = newwin(mainwinHeight, mainwinWidth, mainwinStartY, mainwinStartX);
                sideWin = newwin(sidewinHeight, sidewinWidth, sidewinStartY, sidewinStartX);
                box(mainWin, 0, 0);
                box(sideWin, 0, 0);
                wrefresh(mainWin);
                wrefresh(sideWin);

        }
    }
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

I used the KEY_RESIZE as Thomas suggested and had to delete and recreate the windows on every "resize" key event of the terminal window.

Comment: Actually there is no need to delete and create new windows in my case. Instead one can just use "wresize" to keep the windows at a stable size.